# Having problem with csv export in python with jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, arima

i've tried several solutions that have on stack and each one give me some diferent error. The last one i tried is this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('arima1.csv', sep=';',parse_dates={'Month':[0, 1]}, index_col = 'Month')
df.head()
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('Receita')
plt.plot(df)
```

and i get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this is my CSV file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BlDo10_Oz1RzFEcosiVgdGickXs4elSA/view?usp=sharing

thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV file needs cleaning

```
df = pd.read_csv("arima1.csv",sep='\"+')

# df['Month']= pd.to_datetime(df['Month,'],format="%m/%d/%Y,")
# df['Receita'] = df['Receita'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("R$","").replace(",","")))
# df.set_index(['Month'])['Receita'].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your seperator is ',' not ';'.

When trying to separate by ; you don't have a column named 'Month'

Comment: Please update the question to reflect that. In any case, try only parsing the first column, as the second one does not seem to be a date